# Display Mailchimp Result array in Codeigniter view as a table

Tags: php, arrays, api, codeigniter, mailchimp

I'm developing a **CodeIgniter** application to display **all subscribers** in the ***MailChimp*** list in CodeIgniter **View** as a table. When I use **print_r** command, I got this result below. How to use **foreach** loop to display this properly as a table? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GI2XO.png)

I've uploaded the array here since it is too long and not clear in the attached image:  [enter link description here](https://files.fm/u/j7bfz3sv)

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: try to view the page source, ctrl+u, or right click > view page source, paste it here (with the indentations)

Comment: It doesn't allow me to paste the full code since it contain links. It says I cannot paste more than 10 link in the content.

Comment: I tried to echo array in different ways. Nothing works for me.

Comment: try echo'<pre>';print_r($your_array);die; and take screen shot or try to copy paste it here

Comment: Please provide the code itself. It is hard to determine to object you posted as image and it is not on PRETTY format.

Comment: @M.Hemant and Roshan, I will change the question and add an sample from this array as it is too long

Comment: @M.Hemant, I uploaded the result HTML file here https://files.fm/u/j7bfz3sv. Could you please check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as below:

```
//$your_array is name of array you declare
$members = $your_array['members']
echo '<table>';

foreach ($members as $member) {
  echo '<tr><td>' . $member['email_address'] . '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this in the view file

```
foreach($members as $member){
    echo $member['email_address'];
}
```

Comment: I've already tried it. It says  Undefined index: email_address

Comment: @NSJ what is the result of this `foreach($members as $member){
    print_r($member); break;
}`